# Detailed infromation about this command

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am newbie in Linux and so need to know a detailed information regarding explanation of this command

```
sudo bash -c 'for i in update {,dist-}upgrade auto{remove,clean}; do apt-get $i -y; done'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command can be broken down into the following parts:

- `sudo`: With root privilege
- `bash -c '...'`: Execute the command wrapped in single quotes with bash, the standard shell coming along with most linux distros
- `for i in update {,dist-}upgrade auto{remove,clean}; do ...; done`: This is a for loop in bash. 

   The part `update {,dist-}upgrade auto{remove,clean}` is actually an array with elements being `update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, autoremove, autoclean`, and the variable `i` will take each of these values in order. You'll get more information in [advanced bash script guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#EX22).
- `apt-get $i -y`: What is finally executed. `i` is the loop variable. `-y` means answer yes by default. You can find more information with the command `man apt-get`.

So basically this command is equivalent to the following commands

`sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y`

That's a complete upgrade and cleanup of the softwares in your system.